# How to remove bundler on a mac

Tags: ruby, bundler

I am getting a whole bunch of these errors:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
/Users/robpaulo/gems/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt_ext.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
```

On all my versions of Ruby and I want to see if either my gems are messed or if I have to re-install rbenv. I am running Snow Leopard is there a way to uninstall bundler so that I can re-install it I tried the [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) website and calling `bundle -h` in the console, no help there.

Then I tried `bundle implode` to which bundle laughed maniacally. I also tried `bundle uninstall` which didn't work.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Bundler is just a regular gem, so you'd do:

```
gem uninstall bundler
```

If you want to removal all gems so you're back at a clean slate, just do:

```
gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs gem uninstall -aIx
```

Comment: when trying to run the uninstall --all i get, ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Please specify at least one gem name (e.g. gem build GEMNAME)

Comment: Sorry about that, I've revised the suggestion for removing all gems.

Comment: i do gem uninstall bundler, but then i try to execute bundle comments it works fine. so it isn't getting uninstalled

Comment: I'm having the same problem as amitava...I'd like to find where bundler is installed and remove it. If anyone figures this out, please help.

Comment: @EddieGreathouse running the "which bundler" command shows the install location in most cases.